# .net core api database context foreach

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, api

Momentarily i am working on an API. I just deployed my API to an online environment. now my problem i came across is the following:

Locally, my API had no problems whatsoever, the problem started when i deployed it.

I debugged my program and this was the problem:

```
var setups = _context.Setup;

 foreach (var setup in setups) //<-- problem
                {
                    if (setup.SetupID == setupItems.SetupID)
                    {
                        setup.SetupName = setupItems.SetupName;
                        counter++; //if it is already  in the database
                    }
                }
```

My new MSSQL database gets stuck on this foreach loop, it returns a 404 error the moment it gets in.
For comparison underneath are the developer as well as the deployment connection string:

**Development**

```
Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=***;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

**Deployment**

```
Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=***;User ID=***;Password=***;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

**Question**
How do I solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

The problem is that my online database items are not recognized. 
I tried validating my connection string using this method in console:

```
$conn.ConnectionString = "myConncetionString" # whatever you are testing
$conn.Open()
$conn.Close()
```

The connection string connected perfectly.

I migrated all the tables in it as well that won't be the problem. for info I am using MSSQL MyLittleAdmin as database. Permissions are not the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Do you receiving any exception in your code? Please share exact exception you are receiving in your code.

You have two issues here - first: you should materialize the query (_context.Setup.ToList()) otherwise each row is materializing separately what generates a lot of communication between your app and the db. Secund: if your query (collection) will be materialized it is good idea to to stop tracking the changes in the foreach - better is to "search for the changes" just before "Save Changes" to the db

Here is the code, as I would implement it:

```
var setups = _context.Setup.Where(x => x.SetupID == setupItems.SetupID).ToList();

foreach (var setup in setups)
{
   setup.SetupName = setupItems.SetupName;
}
```

I think I don't know exact context of your code - foreach through all records in the table is not very good idea :) even your exact issue is somewhere else..

Comment: you might want to explain your answer with some code so it will validate as an answer

Comment: I noticed the issues, thanks for the update, though it was not the answer to my problem.